# Failure to generate user instance of SQL Server error, when setup application is run on another computer

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, setup-project

I am unable to run my c# application on a different computer other than my own computer. I have an attached mdf database file in my project. I have 'SQL SERVER 2008' as pre-requisite in the setup project. The application is installing & running fine on my machine, but when i install and run it on another machine, it shows the following error:

```
Description:
Stopped working

Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   esbi.exe
Problem Signature 02:   1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03:   4dd8feca
Problem Signature 04:   System.Data
Problem Signature 05:   2.0.0.0
Problem Signature 06:   4a274a01
Problem Signature 07:   2744
Problem Signature 08:   11
Problem Signature 09:   System.Data.SqlClient.Sql
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
Locale ID:  1033
```

So, I planted a try-catch block on the first opening of connection to the database & caught the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Failed to generate a user interface of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed.

The connection string i am using to connect to the database is

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\esbi.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

what am i doing wrong?? Is it something with the connection string??
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It could be the ".\SQLEXPRESS" in the connection string.  When I deploy to my server that runs the full version of SQL I have to change that to "(local)".

Comment: Any luck with that suggestion?

Comment: He solved the problem with your suggestion. see his answer at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/winformssetup/thread/7515871d-da30-46e8-a335-51546cde0a86

Answer (score -1):

I had a wpf app that ran on my development machine but gave the System.Data.SqlClient.Sql error when deployed to a server. In my project I changed the "Target profile:" on the "Application" tab from 
".NET Framework 4 Client_profile" to 
".NET Framework 4" and then closed, opened and relinked it.
The app then ran without the error as the server had a matching .NET framework